# ajax post call does not return any json response to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am facing issue with ajax post type call. I get blank php json response when an ajax call is invoked from jquery.

Below are the html, jquery and php code which i am using in-order to send HTML form data and get the json response.Please advice if there is any issue with the code or if it has got to do something with the browser settings.

i am using jQuery src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js".
Also using FirePHP addon, i am able to see the form inputs are correctly sent to php.

```
 HTML Code
 =========

  <form id = "frmLogin" action ="" autocomplete="off" style="width:10em;margin:0 auto" method="post">
   User Email ID : <input type = "email" name ="loginId" autocomplete = "off">              
  Password    : <input type = "password" name = "password" autocomplete = "off"> 
  <input id= "clkLogin" type="Submit" value="Submit" >  
  </form>

JQuery Code
===========
$("#frmLogin").submit(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup( { cache: false });      
    $.ajax( {     
        url: "http://localhost/validateUser.php" , 
        cache:false, 
        type:"POST",
        async:true, 
        data: $("form#frmLogin").serialize(),
        success:function(data){
                    $("#loginPage").hide();
                    $("#Registered").hide(); 
                    $("#userHomePage").show();
                                     $("button#user").html(data.firstName);     
            }, dataType:"json" 
           });
         return false;  
        });

 PHP Code
 ========

 <?php
 require_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","kpns@123","spa");

 if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "MYSQL connection error ::" . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $sql = "select * from spausers where email_id = '$_POST[loginId]' and pswd ='$_POST[password]' "; 

 fb($sql,'SQL Query'); // FirePHP console log shows sql statement with  the correct inputs sent from HTML form

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 fb($result,'mysqli_query result');

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $data =    array ('emailid'=>$row['email_id'],'firstName' => $row['first_name'],'lastName' => $row['last_name']);  

 fb(json_encode($data),'mysqli_query fetch array'); // FirePHP console log shows result in json format {"key" : "value", "key":"value"}  
 }
 header("Content-Type: application/json");

 echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

## Request Header

Accept  `*`/`*`

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5

Content-Length  52

Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Host    localhost

Origin  null

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0

## Response Header

Connection  Keep-Alive

Content-Length  85

Content-Type    application/json

Date    Sun, 06 Oct 2013 04:48:54 GMT

Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100

Server  Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) PHP/5.3.27

X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.27

Comment: is the ajax success function being run?

Comment: There's a typo in `dateType:"json"`, should be `dataType`

Comment: Where is the closing **}** of **while** loop ?

Comment: No the ajax success function is not being run. The dateType is was actually a typo. I had used the dataType = 'json' and the problem still remains.

Comment: While loop has a closing brace. Probably while formating the code to make it fit in stackoverflow it would have got deleted. Just to add some more info about this problem. I can see in firebug the response code is showing 200 ok but in response tab it is just a blank response. Just curious to know if this problem has something to do with the apache2.2 settings in-order to serve the php response ?. Looking forward for all your inputs/suggestions !!!

Comment: When i used a ajax call with a php to insert some html form value into mysql database, i was able to insert the values into database. However i am observing problem only when trying to returning any response from php back to jquery irrespective of any format.

Comment: Try adding an `error: function() { }` after the success function to console log the error.

Answer (score -1):

Hope can help you

## JQuery Code

```
$("#frmLogin").submit(function() {

    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);
    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $.ajaxSetup( { cache: false });      
    $.ajax( {  
        cache:false, 
        type:"POST",
        async:true, 
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost/validateUser.php",
        data: serializedData,
        success:function(data){
                $("#loginPage").hide();
                $("#Registered").hide(); 
                $("#userHomePage").show();
                $("button#user").html(data.firstName);     
        }
       });
     return false;  
    });
```